# How to detect if ajax error is Access-Control-Allow-Origin or the file is actually missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My question is NOT about how to solve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues. This errors will happen sometimes when performing requests, and other times the url's might be outdated. But I want to print different messages for the user depending on the different errors.

Currently I have the following code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: link,
    type:'HEAD',
    timeout: 2000,
    error: function(request, status, message)
    {
        console.log('ajax error');
        console.log(request);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(message);
        openPopUp("There was an error accessing the image. It can be because the address is invalid, "+
            "or because the server where the image is stored is not allowing direct access to the images.");
    },
    success: function()
    {
        // More stuff here
    }
});
```

Looking at the console it's easy to see if the file was actually missing, or if it was an Access-Control problem. But i'd like to print out two different messages to the user saying exactly what the problem was. Looking at the variables in error: function(request, status, message) they do not change, both cases result in a 404 error. Is there some other was to do this so that I can know what the problem was?

Thank you in advance for the attention.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser console shows you

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

but you cannot access this information yourself with JavaScript alone. When a browser detects a CORS violation, it will [discard the header information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as a matter of protocol.

---

One solution that works is to inspect the response headers using server-side code and pass the results back to your client page. For example, if the ajax request fails, you could call this script (let's call it `cors.php`) and know for certain if it contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or not.

Example:

> cors.php?url=http://ip.jsontest.com
>   cors.php?url=http://www.google.com

returns

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   None

Thus, you can do the following in your JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  timeout: 4000,
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      // Simple not found page, but not CORS violation
      console.log(this.url + " not found" );
    }
  }
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   // Empty status is a sign that this may be a CORS violation
   // but also check if the request timed out, or that the domain exists
   if(jqXHR.status > 0 || jqXHR.statusText == "timeout") {
      console.log("Failure because: "+jqXHR.status+" "+jqXHR.statusText+" error"); 
      return;
   }

   // Determine if this was a CORS violation or not
   console.log("Checking if this is a CORS violation at - " + this.url);
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://myserver.net/cors.php?url=" + escape(this.url),
   })
   .done(function(msg) {
      // Check for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
      if(msg.indexOf("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") >= 0) {
        console.log("Failed bacause '" + msg + "'");
      } else {
        console.log("Failed bacause of CORS violation");
      }
   });
})
.done(function(msg) {
  // Successful ajax request
  console.log(msg);
}); /* Drakes, 2015 */
```

Customize this PHP script for your own needs:

```
<?php 
/* cors.php */

$url = $_GET["url"];
if(isset($url)) {
    $headers = getHeaders($url, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // Allow your own cross-site requests
    echo count($headers) > 0 ? $headers[0] : "None";
}

// Get the response headers, only specific ones
function getHeaders($url, $needle = false) {
    $headers = array();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD'); // Only get the headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $header_line) use(&$headers, $needle) {
        if(!$needle || strpos($header_line, $needle) !== false) {
            array_push($headers, $header_line);
        }
        return strlen($header_line);
    });
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch); 
    return $headers;
} /* Drakes, 2015 */
```

Comment: +1 for "When a browser detects a CORS violation, **it will discard the header information** as a matter of protocol.". This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to read the response header from the request object:

var acao = request.getResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');

then output the appropriate error based on whether the header exists and whether your url is in the value.

Comment: That would seem a good way to go but unfortunately when the problem is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin I don't have access to the headers. Even using getAllResponseHeaders() I get an empty list.

Comment: What changes in the console? Could you post a couple of examples of the different cases? Seems like if you can see the difference in the console it should be available to you somewhere...

Comment: Sure. When I try to access an image that exists but i can't access i get the error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mylink. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mysite' is therefore not allowed access. If I try to open a wrong link I get: HEAD http://wronglink net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED